# laravel cannot declare class because the name is already in use in config file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I made `config/Consts/MyConst.php`

```
<?php                                                                                                                                                                                            

namespace App\Consts;

class MyConst
{
// some code
}
```

and put `config/app.php`

```
'MyConst' => App\Consts\MyConst::class,
```

I think this is typical const file.
When I do php artisan test, I get :

> PHP Fatal error:  Cannot declare class App\Consts\MyConst, because the
> name is already in use in /Users/~~~~/config/Consts/MyConst.php on
> line 5

I know this error shown when I made mistake writing namespace but I can not find it.

When I use `MyConst` from other files such as controller or view, it works well.
Only (for now) in test, this error shows. Do you have any advice ?

Comment: config/Consts/MyConst.php is not App\Consts

Comment: `'MyConst' => \App\Consts\MyConst::class` and `php artisan config:cache` should work

Comment: Hi nice_dev. Thanks. I tried php artisan config:cache, then i got same error "Cannot declare class~~~~"

Answer (score 1):

i think if you create new class with not matching namespace, composer will throw a warning.(App\Consts,config/Consts). and 'config' area not autoload as psr-4 becouse its not defined in composer.json "autoload": area.
so its better to create folder in app\Consts and put the class inside that folder.

then, create file `MyConst.php` and add class like below.

```
<?php                                                                                                                                                                                            

namespace App\Consts;

class MyConst
{
    public const EXAMPLE_CONST = 'test';
}
```

then, in app.php file in config folder, add your class in `aliases' section in app.php file

```
<?php 
...
 'aliases' => [
...
'MyConst' => App\Consts\MyConst::class,
...
```

run  a config clear `php artisan config:clear`

test it, (i tested in route file)

```
Route::get('/testconst', function () {
    dd(MyConst::EXAMPLE_CONST);
});
```

[image]

edit:
but if you need to use in a another class, you have to import class (eg: `use MyConst;`)  first or use with slash eg: `\MyConst::EXAMPLE_CONST` else it will throw error.